# Pulling JSON Data into R Dataframe

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I am trying to pull JSON lunar cycle data from the USNO API.  The problem is that there are two arrays of JSON data in what I get back.  I don't see a way to specify what I get back from the Observatory, so I think I need to clean it up in R.  Here is my code:

```
library(sqldf);
library(jsonlite);

curr_date <- Sys.Date();
Q_date <- format.Date(curr_date, "%m/%d/%Y");
moon_call <- paste0("http://api.usno.navy.mil/moon/phase?date=",Q_date,"&nump=4");

moon_json <- fromJSON(moon_call, simplifyDataFrame =  TRUE);

moon_phases <- do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(moon_json$phasedata, as.data.frame));
```

The data I get back looks like this:

```
"","error","apiversion","year","month","day","numphases","datechanged","phasedata.phase","phasedata.date","phasedata.time"
"1",FALSE,"2.1.0",2018,8,29,4,FALSE,"Last Quarter","2018 Sep 03","02:37"
"2",FALSE,"2.1.0",2018,8,29,4,FALSE,"New Moon","2018 Sep 09","18:01"
"3",FALSE,"2.1.0",2018,8,29,4,FALSE,"First Quarter","2018 Sep 16","23:15"
"4",FALSE,"2.1.0",2018,8,29,4,FALSE,"Full Moon","2018 Sep 25","02:52"
```

When convert it to a data frame I get this:

```
"","X[[i]]"
"1","Last Quarter"
"2","New Moon"
"3","First Quarter"
"4","Full Moon"
"5","2018 Sep 03"
"6","2018 Sep 09"
"7","2018 Sep 16"
"8","2018 Sep 25"
"9","02:37"
"10","18:01"
"11","23:15"
"12","02:52"
```

But what I want is a dataframe with the `phasedata.phase/.date/.time` columns selected:

```
"","phase","date","time"
"1","Last Quarter","2018 Sep 03","02:37"
"2","New Moon","2018 Sep 09","18:01"
"3","First Quarter","2018 Sep 16","23:15"
"4","Full Moon","2018 Sep 25","02:52"
```

Comment: so, does your code work well? in which part you wish to do improvment?

Comment: Are you specifically after the `phasedata` - i.e., `moon_json$phasedata` ? I think the line `do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(moon_json, as.data.frame));` is throwing you off course

Comment: Yes, I only want the phasedata.  Making the change I now only get what I want, but it is one column of data, not three.
`"","X[[i]]"
"1","Last Quarter"
"2","New Moon"` etc

Comment: What change have you made? Please edit your question to clarify what changes you've made and what you're now seeing. Also include a value for `curr_date`

Comment: I altered the conversion to only get the moon phase data `moon_phases <- do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(moon_json$phasedata, as.data.frame));`

`curr_date` is just the system date (`curr_date <- Sys.Date();`), I had to reformat it for the api call.  This was run a few days ago and is running for August 29th, 2018.

Comment: Please edit your question with your updated code and requirements; don't add them as a comment.

Comment: and doesn't `moon_json$phasedata` give you what you want?

Comment: Not really, because I get a list and not a table.  I need three columns with four rows, not one column with twelve rows.

I edited the code to show the latest revision.

Comment: `moon_json$phasedata` IS a data.frame of 3 columns, 4 rows. Forget all the `do.call()` stuff.

Comment: Ah, that's got it, thanks!

`moon_phases <- moon_json$phasedata;`

Comment: Please be clearer; instead of saying *"The data I get back looks like this"* and *"When convert it to a data frame I get this"*, state which of your lists/dataframes you're referring to; it's unclear if you mean *"moon_call looks like this"* and *"moon_json (/moon_phases) looks like this"*. Anyway I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

1. R allows you to directly [extract the three columns](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html) from the dataframe `moon_json`, like you want:

   `moon_phases <- moon_json[, c('phasedata.phase', 'phasedata.date', 'phasedata.time')]`

(No need whatsoever for the `do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(..., as.data.frame))` - that's just a inefficient and tortured way of slicing and then concatenating.)

2. Then you want to rename your df columns to drop the `phasedata.` prefix:

   `names(moon_phases) <- c('phase', 'date', 'time')`

or: `names(moon_phases) <- gsub('^phasedata\.', '', names(moon_phases))`

3. Also, you generally don't want explicit rownames `1,2,3...` on your dataframes like `moon_json`, so just do `row.names(moon_json) <- NULL` or `data.frame(..., row.names=NULL)` or `as.data.frame(..., row.names=NULL)`

(`jsonlite` (or else one of the other R json packages) should have options to do this cleanup and renaming automatically, I don't know, I don't use them much. Check them out and pick a package that makes scraping less painful.)